# Installing Radian (base) vs (env)

Tags: python, r, conda

Normally I never install to (base), but since Miniforge and other package managers come with python in (base), I'm wondering if I should install Radian in (base) as well.

VS Code's `RTerm` path setting allows for Radian, but changing that path every new project is not realistic. I should just be able to select my R kernel each time I open a workspace and that's it.

If I install Radian in `(base)` then I cannot run the Radian console from other environments because I have to activate `(base)` to get the R console.

Should I just dump Radian into every `(env)` and yaml everything out? Seems very unintuitive to install radian in every environment. What is the convention for Radian in production vs develop?

I know we can install Radian via pip as well, but same question. In each (env)?

Should the VS Code `Rterm` path be (base)?
`/Users/edison/miniforge3/bin/radian`
or each (env)?
`/Users/edison/miniforge3/envs/csat-env/bin/radian`

VS Code `Rpath`
`/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R`